# Calling main activity shows Activity not found exception

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-manifest

I am trying to call the main activity, but it shows activity not found exception. I can't recreate this issue in house. but so many users of my app were facing this issue.

Any suggestion to recreate this issue.

My code here:

```
      Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
      intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
      activity.startActivity(intent);
```

My main activity in my manifest file

```
             <activity android:name="com.example.EntryAct" android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|navigation" android:label="@string/app_name">
                          <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                          </intent-filter>
                          </activity>
```

Crash Log

```
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] flg=0x10000000 }
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1878)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1545)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4567)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4535)
        at com.example.SlideManager.onEvent(SlideManager.java:797)
        at com.example.SlideManager.handleBackPressed(SlideManager.java:484)
        at com.example.HostActivity.onBackPressed(BaseHostActivity.java:628)
        at android.app.Activity.onKeyUp(Activity.java:2712)
        at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:3273)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2982)
```

And i analyzed in stackoverflow to check whether we can call the activity (that is checking the calling activity status). there one function i got, that is below

```
        private boolean isCallable(Intent intent) {List<ResolveInfo> list = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, 
                PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                return list.size() > 0;
        }
```

My list of question:

1. Why i cant reproduce this issue in house.
2. Can i use mentioned solution to avoid crash. is this good go?
3. Why this crash happening fro particular user.

Need you help guys. please help me...

Comment: post you exception logs

Comment: @AshishShukla Added the crash log. please it

Comment: why you are adding thi sline intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);

Comment: In your code you are calling "LoginActivity", In manifest you have declared  "com.example.EntryAct "  ?

Comment: @sunilsunny it my mistake. i changed it.

Comment: @Vji removing this line should fix your problem "intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);"  since the crash is on that.Is it really necessary that in your app ?. Also change your intent initialization to  `Intent intent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.Class);`

Comment: Thanks... i will try it out @sunilsunny. how to reproduce this issue?

Comment: May be it's reproducable in some phones only ,I am not sure about it.. Check with your users  in which phones the crash is happening and search if there are any issues with this line  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME); for those phone models.

Comment: Will try those things @sunilsunny and thanks for your support!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129319/discussion-between-vji-and-sunil-sunny).

Comment: @sunilsunny how this Intent.CATEGORY_HOME relates to Activity Not found exception

Comment: @Vji it's in your exception itself ..What is your actual code.Your question and the code you posted are different I guess.

Comment: Please post your log.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
  intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
  intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  activity.startActivity(intent);
```